# How does reverse image search engine works?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, search, search-engine

I have seen few reverse image search engines such as Google Lens, SauceNAO, IQDB and etc.

And I wonder how these engines work with very fast speed, even they have to load image from other site(In case of sauceNAO, they get illustration works from pixiv - which has about 1 million arts in total) and check it's image similarity.

Can anyone explain me how these engines work?

Comment: You could compare color-histograms (maybe in a specialized color-domain) of as reduced color-pallet to eliminate most non similar images very fast (also you can precalculate the histograms in advance and store them in a DB). For images with similar histogramms you can try moore suffisticated comparisons like frequency analysis,  ... The www is full of articles how to compare images for similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They use image fingerprinting/hashes, in image hashes similar input results in similar output not like crypthgraphic hashing where one small change in the input produces a completely different output.

So if they have indexed a lot of image hashes that they find by crawling the web, then they can quickly check if the hash of the uploaded image is similar to one that they have indexed

https://pypi.org/project/ImageHash/

Comment: You cannot tell how similar images are by their hash. A hash can only tell you if the images are identical or not. I suggest you describe more clearly what these algorithms do, as the current text is insufficient without the link. And we don’t want such answers here, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/376604

Comment: @CrisLuengo Read into the link, in image hashes you want similar input to be similar output not like you have it in cryptographic hashing